# How to prepare data for training and data for predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new in TensorFlow and Machine Learning (python also).
In first step to create an image recognition program, i was hit the wall of confusion in feeding data preparation. Can someone please help me on this?
I was look into this tutorial, but the data preparation is obfuscated. 
[mnis softmax for beginner](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py)

I didn't expect to get a whole perfect program from this question, instead i would love to hear if you can tell me how TensorFlow work on feed_dict. For now in my mind, it is: "Work like a [for] loop, go though imageHolder, get the data of 2352 byte/ 1 image and put in the training op, in there it's perform predict base on current model and compare with data from labelHolder of same index then perform correction on model." so i was expect to put in a set of 2352 byte data (another image with same size) and get the prediction. I will also put the code here, in case my idea is correct and the error come from bad implementation.

---

Said: i have a set off data for 5 classes, with 3670 images in total.
When load the data to feed_dict for training, i have converted all image to 28x28 pixels, with 3 channels. it result me a tensor of (3670, 2352) for image holder in the feed_dict. After that, i managed to prepare a tensor of (3670,) for label holder in the feed_dict.
The training code is look like this:

```
for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
        feed_dict = {
            imageHolder: imageTrain,
            labelHolder: labelTrain,
        }
        _, loss_rate = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Then i have my code to predict a new image with the model above:

```
testing_dataset = do_get_file_list(FLAGS.guess_dir)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(IMAGE_PIXELS))
for data in testing_dataset:
    image = Image.open(data)
    image = image.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
    image = np.array(image).reshape(IMAGE_PIXELS)
    prediction = session.run(tf.argmax(logits, 1), feed_dict={x: image})
```

But the problem is the predict line always raise an error of "Can not feed value of shape...." no matter what shape my testing data is (2352,), (1, 2352) (it's ask for (3670, 2352) shape, but no way)

---

This is some flag i have used

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 28
CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_PIXELS = IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * CHANNELS
```

The training op and loss computing:

```
def do_get_op_compute_loss(logits, labels):
    labels = tf.to_int64(labels)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits, name='xentropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    return loss

def do_get_op_training(loss_op, training_rate):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op
```

Variables

```
imageHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [data_count, IMAGE_PIXELS])
labelHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [data_count])
```

For complete program:

```
import os
import math
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from six.moves import xrange

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 200, 'Number of steps to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 128, 'Number of units in hidden layer 1.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden2', 32, 'Number of units in hidden layer 2.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 4, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', 'data', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('save_file', '.\\data\\model.ckpt', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('guess_dir', 'work', 'Directory to put the testing data.')
#flags.DEFINE_boolean('fake_data', False, 'If true, uses fake data '
#                    'for unit testing.')

IMAGE_SIZE = 28
CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_PIXELS = IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * CHANNELS

def do_inference(images, hidden1_units, hidden2_units, class_count):
    #HIDDEN LAYER 1
    with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
        weights = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS, hidden1_units], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(IMAGE_PIXELS))),
            name='weights')
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]), name='biases')
        hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights) + biases)
    #HIDDEN LAYER 2
    with tf.name_scope('hidden1'):
        weights = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([hidden1_units, hidden2_units], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden1_units))),
            name='weights')
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden2_units]), name='biases')
        hidden2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden1, weights) + biases)
    #LINEAR
    with tf.name_scope('softmax_linear'):
        weights = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([hidden2_units, class_count], stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(hidden2_units))),
            name='weights')
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='biases')
        logits = tf.matmul(hidden2, weights) + biases
    return logits

def do_get_op_compute_loss(logits, labels):
    labels = tf.to_int64(labels)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits, name='xentropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    return loss

def do_get_op_training(loss_op, training_rate):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op

def do_get_op_evaluate(logits, labels):
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct, tf.int32))

def do_evaluate(session, eval_correct_op, imageset_holder, labelset_holder, train_images, train_labels):
    true_count = 0
    num_examples = FLAGS.batch_size * FLAGS.batch_size
    for step in xrange(FLAGS.batch_size):
        feed_dict = {imageset_holder: train_images, labelset_holder: train_labels,}
        true_count += session.run(eval_correct_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        precision = true_count / num_examples
    # print('  Num examples: %d  Num correct: %d  Precision @ 1: %0.04f' %
        # (num_examples, true_count, precision))

def do_init_param(data_count, class_count): 
    # Generate placeholder
    imageHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(data_count, IMAGE_PIXELS))
    labelHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(data_count))

    # Build a graph for prediction from inference model
    logits = do_inference(imageHolder, FLAGS.hidden1, FLAGS.hidden2, class_count)

    # Add loss calculating op
    loss_op = do_get_op_compute_loss(logits, labelHolder)

    # Add training op
    train_op = do_get_op_training(loss_op, FLAGS.learning_rate)

    # Add evaluate correction op
    evaluate_op = do_get_op_evaluate(logits, labelHolder)

    # Create session for op operating
    sess = tf.Session()

    # Init param
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    return sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, logits

def do_get_class_list():
    return [{'name': name, 'path': os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, name)} for name in os.listdir(FLAGS.train_dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, name))]

def do_get_file_list(folderName):
    return [os.path.join(folderName, name) for name in os.listdir(folderName)
            if (os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folderName, name)) == False)]

def do_init_data_list():
    file_list = []
    for classItem in do_get_class_list():
        for dataItem in do_get_file_list(classItem['path']):
            file_list.append({'name': classItem['name'], 'path': dataItem})

    # Renew data feeding dictionary
    imageTrainList, labelTrainList = do_seperate_data(file_list)
    imageTrain = []
    for imagePath in imageTrainList:
        image = Image.open(imagePath)
        image = image.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
        imageTrain.append(np.array(image))

    imageCount = len(imageTrain)
    imageTrain = np.array(imageTrain)
    imageTrain = imageTrain.reshape(imageCount, IMAGE_PIXELS)

    id_list, id_map = do_generate_id_label(labelTrainList)
    labelTrain = np.array(id_list)
    return imageTrain, labelTrain, id_map

def do_init():
    imageTrain, labelTrain, id_map = do_init_data_list()
    sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, logits = do_init_param(len(imageTrain), len(id_map))
    return sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, imageTrain, labelTrain, id_map, logits

def do_seperate_data(data):
    images = [item['path'] for item in data]
    labels = [item['name'] for item in data]
    return images, labels

def do_generate_id_label(label_list):
    trimmed_label_list = list(set(label_list))
    id_map = {trimmed_label_list.index(label): label for label in trimmed_label_list}
    reversed_id_map = {label: trimmed_label_list.index(label) for label in trimmed_label_list}
    id_list = [reversed_id_map.get(item) for item in label_list]
    return id_list, id_map

def do_training(sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, imageTrain, labelTrain):
    # Training state checkpoint saver
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # feed_dict = {
        # imageHolder: imageTrain,
        # labelHolder: labelTrain,
    # }

    for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):
        feed_dict = {
            imageHolder: imageTrain,
            labelHolder: labelTrain,
        }
        _, loss_rate = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        if step % 100 == 0:
            print('Step {0}: loss = {1}'.format(step, loss_rate))
        if (step + 1) % 1000 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
            saver.save(sess, FLAGS.save_file, global_step=step)
            print('Evaluate training data')
            do_evaluate(sess, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, imageTrain, labelTrain)

def do_predict(session, logits):
    # xentropy
    testing_dataset = do_get_file_list(FLAGS.guess_dir)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(IMAGE_PIXELS))
    print('Perform predict')
    print('==================================================================================')
    # TEMPORARY CODE
    for data in testing_dataset:
        image = Image.open(data)
        image = image.resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
        image = np.array(image).reshape(IMAGE_PIXELS)
        print(image.shape)
        prediction = session.run(logits, {x: image})
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(data, prediction))

def main(_):
    # TF notice default graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, imageTrain, labelTrain, id_map, logits = do_init()
        print("done init")
        do_training(sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, imageTrain, labelTrain)
        print("done training")
        do_predict(sess, logits)

# NO IDEA
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand the error, you say

> But the problem is the predict line always raise an error of "Can not
>   feed value of shape...." no matter what shape my testing data is
>   (2352,), (1, 2352) (it's ask for (3670, 2352) shape, but no way)

Oh yes way my friend, yes way. It says there's a problem with your shape, you need to inspect that. It asks for 3670, why?

Because your model accepts inputs with shape (data_count, IMAGE_PIXELS), which you declare in the below:

```
def do_init_param(data_count, class_count): 
    # Generate placeholder
    imageHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(data_count, IMAGE_PIXELS))
    labelHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(data_count))
```

This function is called here:

```
sess, train_op, loss_op, evaluate_op, imageHolder, labelHolder, logits = do_init_param(len(imageTrain), len(id_map))
```

`len(imageTrain)` is the length of your dataset, probably 3670 images.

Then you have your prediction function:

```
def do_predict(session, logits):
    # xentropy
    testing_dataset = do_get_file_list(FLAGS.guess_dir)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(IMAGE_PIXELS))
    ...
    prediction = session.run(logits, {x: image})
```

Note `x` here is useless. You are feeding your image to predict to your model which does not expect that shape, it expects the original placeholder shape of (3670, 2352), because that's what you said.

The solution is to declare `x` as a placeholder with non-specific first dimension such as:

```
imageHolder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, IMAGE_PIXELS))
```

When you predict the label of your image, you can have a single image or multiple images (a mini-batch), but always must be of shape [number_images, IMAGE_PIXELS].

Makes sense?

Comment: Hello vega,  
Thank you very much for your great effort to explain.
I'm trying to understand, but it's kind of none sense since we have to predict with the same amount of image used to train the model, or is it the reason to not over fed data in training stage? I had tried the "non-specific" first dimension before, but seem it's only matter in code and function param.  
(In my imagination, [number_images, IMAGE_PIXELS] hold - in this case - 3670x2352 bytes, but i only need to predict on 1 image - 2352 bytes - the rest can be set as 0, but why? Will TensorFlow ignore the extra?)